# IDs of contents of "TabHost.TabContentFactory()"

Tags: java, android

I have a question that I couldn't find the answer among already asked questions. Here you see a simple code, that by receiving a click construct a new tab with a simple textview.
If we want to integrate more with the newly built tab, how could we address the contents of it?
For instance if I want add two numbers in two newly made tabs and put it in a third tab...
In this code, which works perfectly, I add a textview by name of text! How can I address two textviews on two different tabs?!
I hope my question was clear. 
Thanks. :)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bAddTab:

        TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        ourSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView text = new TextView(Tabs.this);
                text.setText("You've created a new Tab!");
                return null;
            }
        });
        ourSpec.setIndicator("New");
        th.addTab(ourSpec);
        break;
```